# shorthand javascript ? for making vars?

Tags: javascript, jquery

Is there a bether way to do this ?
i try serval things, but this one is the only that works for me

```
var naam = $("#resvNaam").val();
var aantal = $("#resvAantal").val();
var uur = $("#resvUur").val();
var datum = $("#resvDatum").val();
var telefoon = $("#resvTelefoon").val();
var opmerking = $("#resvOpmerking").val();
var alles = "?naam=" + naam + "&aantal=" + aantal + "&uur=" + uur + "&datum=" + datum + "&telefoon=" + telefoon + "&opmerking=" + opmerking;
```

Comment: You can use a single `var` instance: `var foo = "", bar = "";`

Comment: You're not stupid. There's a lot we don't know; fortunately Stack Overflow helps us fill in those gaps more easily.

Comment: If you can give them names instead of (or along with) ids, you can simply use `form.serialize` to get the query string.

Comment: @PhilAndelhofs Please don't add answers to your question. If you'd like to add an answer based on what Jonathan Sampson told you, you can do so, down in the Answers section.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can put all the ids in an array, then use `map`:

```
var ids = [
  'naam',
  'aantal',
  ...
]

var ucfirst = function(x) {
  return x[0].toUpperCase() + x.slice(1)
}

var alles = '?'+ ids
  .map(function(id) {
    var value = encodeURIComponent($('#resv'+ ucfirst(id)).val())
    return id +'='+ value
  })
  .join('&')
```

I would suggest using the same `id` or `name` for the field and the query, so it is easier to manipulate, and write less code.

As suggested in the comments, if you use names it would be easier to serialize the form with jQuery using http://api.jquery.com/serialize/

Comment: I agree with the suggestion to use `encodeURIComponent`, so why not add it to your example? :)